# Apply conditions in projection level

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql

Is there a simple way to apply conditions in projection level? I mean In a series of fields(columns) how can we choose only the fields those have specific conditions?

---

*Example:*

Assume we have a query with below result:

```
Id  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10   Col11
-   ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----
1   V1_1    NULL    NULL    V4_1    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    V10_1   NULL
2   V1_2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    V10_2   NULL
3   V1_3    NULL    NULL    V4_3    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    V10_3   NULL
```

how can we *`select only the fields which contains none null values while we don't know which of them contains none null values`*? so result would be this:

```
Id  Col1    Col4    Col10
-   ----    ----    ----
1   V1_1    V4_1    V10_1
2   V1_2    NULL    V10_2
3   V1_3    V4_3    V10_3
```

Usually I do such these queries with hardcoding which I may query `sys.all_obejcts`, `sys.all_columns` in `MsSQL Server` and `all_tab_cols`, `all_tables` , etc in `Oracle`. and use none, one or more `cursor`s , `case` statements, `pivot`, multiple `if`s  or `dynamic sql` in it.

in example: for a table with above data in T-SQL I can do:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)
SET @sql='SELECT Id,'
IF EXISTS (SELECT Col1 FROM tblTEST WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL)  SET @sql=@sql+'Col1,'
/* 9 other IF statements here */
IF EXISTS (SELECT Col11 FROM tblTEST WHERE Col11 IS NOT NULL)  SET @sql=@sql+'Col11,'
SET @sql=SUBSTRING(@sql,1,LEN(@sql)-1)+' FROM tblTEST'
EXEC(@sql)
```

but as you see the idea is not common at all and it's a little hard to do such coding for such these scenarios

---

Do you know a simple and better way or a pattern for such this queries?

The RDBMS does not matter, a good solution for any RDBMS is really useful.

Please I want answers to be a good idea in general not only for the example I mentioned.

Comment: This is generally a presentation logic issue.  But if you need a dynamic set of columns, you have to use dynamic sql.  There isn't a database independent way to accomplish this (each flavor is different)...

Comment: Yes, you are right as far as I know. I thought maybe someone has a better idea or info on it or has bean experienced good solution, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a T-SQL solution. All you should have to do is change @TargetTable to your desired table. Hope this helps! I commented my code explaining everything, but if you have any questions, let me know!

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('myTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.myTable;

CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Col1 VARCHAR(25),
    Col2 VARCHAR(25),
    Col3 VARCHAR(25)
)


INSERT INTO dbo.myTable(Col1,Col2,Col3)
    VALUES  ('v1_1',NULL,NULL),
            ('v1_2','v2_2',NULL),
            ('v1_3',NULL,NULL);


/* Now that I've set up the problem, here's for the actual code*/
--Set your desired table
DECLARE @TargetTable VARCHAR(100) = 'myTable'

--If this global temp table exists, drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('##tempTable') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC('DROP TABLE ##tempTable');

--This is going to take one character and cast it to NCHAR(1)
    --If there are no characters, it will simply return NULL
DECLARE @AllColumns VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @AllColumns = COALESCE(@AllColumns + ',','') + 'CAST(LEFT(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ',1) AS NCHAR(1)) AS ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TargetTable

/*Load your char results into a global temp table*/
EXEC('SELECT ' + @AllColumns + ' INTO ##tempTable FROM ' + @TargetTable);

/*Here's where the fun beings*/

/*  @DesiredCol holds the name of columns that are not null.
    UNPIVOT the data.
    Where clause gets rid of columns with only NULL values.
    Group by only allows distinct columns.
    You the select from your ORIGINAL table, not my funky nchar(1) global temp table.
*/

EXEC(

    'DECLARE @DesiredCol VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @DesiredCol = COALESCE(@DesiredCol + '','','''') + QUOTENAME(col)
    FROM ##temptable 
    UNPIVOT
    (
    val FOR col IN ([ID],[Col1],[Col2],[Col3])
    ) pvt
    WHERE pvt.val IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY col

    EXEC (''SELECT '' + @DesiredCol + '' FROM ##' + @TargetTable + ''')'
    )
--Cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('##tempTable') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC('DROP TABLE ##tempTable');
```